# Why should i not use getBoundingClientRect() in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

On my latest project i used the `getBoundingClientRect()`.
Another React engineer told me that i should not use it because browser compatibility.
Shouldn't  this be handled by Webpack/Babel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check browser support for `getBoundingClientRect()` (and pretty much anything else) at caniuse.com.

As you can see there, `getBoundingClientRect()` has been [well supported for a long time](https://caniuse.com/#feat=getboundingclientrect). Make sure to read the footnotes though. Don't use the `x` and `y` properties on the returned object, and you are in the clear.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Webpack will not handle by default cross browser support of browser API's, for that purpose you have to use [polyfills](https://javascript.info/polyfills), but they may have the downside of increasing your bundle size. Depending on what features you are using you can use targeted polyfills (just for one or couple of API's) instead of generic ones, see [Weeding Out Your ES6 Webpack Bundle Sizes](https://medium.com/lendingtree-engineering/weeding-out-your-es6-webpack-bundle-sizes-62cbc5a62a30).

More specific to your question - and depending on what you intend to use `getBoundingClientRect()` for - you could take a look at `react-measure` which is a really good package when it comes to getting size info of your component. I found it very useful when working on advanced react layout applications and I use it in my own resizeable layout component: [react-reflex](https://github.com/leefsmp/re-flex).